# backup restore between Two farms with different patches

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, backup

what is the process to restore a site collection backup from one farm running in sp2010 sp2
into another farm with sp2010 sp1?

what things required after restoring backup or else is there any problem?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restore a site collection from SP2 farm to Sp1. You can restore from Sp1 to Sp2 farm only if you take the Content DB backup not sharepoint site collection backup.

In your current scenario, Only thing is Update your farm to SP2 level and then restore the site collection, Otherwise it will give you version mismatch error.